# Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc, python-db-api

I'm trying to establish connection with Microsoft Office and to run a query but it is showing error

Here is my code:

```py
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=E:\Python\Database\att2000.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT CHECKINOUT FROM att2000 Where CHECKTYPE = O")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

Here is the error:

```
Error is occurring while executing the query
----> 5 cursor.execute("SELECT CHECKINOUT FROM att2000 Where CHECKTYPE = O")
      6 
      7 for row in cursor.fetchall():

ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'att2000'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly. (-1305) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Comment: `att2000` is the name of the database file. Apparently it does not contain a table or view that is also named `att2000`. Open the database in the Microsoft Access UI and verify what the table/view names are.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mix up the file name and the table name.

Try:

```
cursor.execute("Select * From CHECKINOUT Where CHECKTYPE = O")
```